# How to run asp.net in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to install mono-develop to run ASP.NET code and C# 
but mono-develop not working and lunch in my Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there another server or devloper to install to run ASP.NET and C#?

Can anyone help please?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com

Comment: You don't need mono-develop to run the code. Just Mono

Comment: it not working in my ubuntu

Comment: i need to run the asp code to the browser

Comment: have you installed mono? you can't run mono-develop without the mono libraries underneath. I'd have thought it was a dependency but perhaps you installed it a different way. And perhaps defining "not working" more clearly would be better - did it fail to install? Or fail to run? if you run from the command line are there any errors reported?